# Returning the response the server from a fetch when it fails

Tags: javascript

I am doing an API fetch and when the fetch fails the server returns an error object I would like to include in my error message to user. I have tried variations of:

```
.then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response);
      }

      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
     // stuff if fetch succesful
    .catch((error) => {
      aiConversation.value = `I'm sorry. There was a problem with your request at this time. ${error.message}`;
```

[image: Dev tools output]

The server is returning an object called error with a property message. How can I access the response object from server in the catch?

**Update**: Here is what I came up with that works. I would be curious if somebody can show how to use the Throw like i had originally intended.

```
await fetch(openAIURL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(fetchOptions),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        throw new Error(data.error.message);
      }
      // handle response here
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      aiConversation.value =
        `I'm sorry. There was a problem with your request at this time. ${error}`;
      console.error(
        "There has been a problem with your fetch operation:",
        error
      );
    })
```

Comment: Same way you do when it's successful, it's what `response.json()` resolves to.

Comment: I tried that but all  I get when I console.log error in the throw block Error: [object Promise]

Comment: Then I guess you didn't resolve the promise (e.g. with `await`).

Comment: I did: .catch(async (error) => {
      await error;
      console.log(error.message);   , but still only get Error [object promise].

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Presumably you've thrown `new Error(res.body())`, i.e. an error whose "message" is a promise of the response body. You're awaiting the error, which is not itself a promise so "resolves" immediately.

Comment: That's what I had thought  originally. I was trying to work an await in there to see if it made any difference. Doesn't the .catch work like .then and awaits fetch to resolve and I should be able to access res.body in the catch?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally dependent on the client you use. Most clients have a hook for intercepting calls before they hit promise callbacks. You would set this up when you setup the client and not on a call-by-call basis.

Here is an [example for fetch](https://blog.logrocket.com/intercepting-javascript-fetch-api-requests-responses/), for example

Comment: I am using the native fetch API.

Comment: The answer still applies. Check the docs for how to install an interceptor